# How to convert this LINQ query from methods form to fluent syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query in method syntax format:

```
items.Select (item => fieldsNames.Select(fieldName => item
                                 .FieldValues[fieldName])
                                 .ToList ())
     .ToList();
```

What is the equivalent in fluent query syntax?

I've tried

```
(from item in items
from fieldName in fieldsNames
select item.FieldValues[fieldName]).ToList()
```

but that gives me a single `List<T>` instead of a `List<List<T>`

Comment: Why do yo want to do this? If it works using the extension methods directly, why not just leave it as it is?

Comment: Instead of using nested `ToList()`, try using `SelectMany()` as Lee mentions.

Comment: @ColinMackay: why? because I wanted to know. Simply. ;)

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan: using SelectMany() only gives me a list<T> instead of a List<List<T>> as explained in the last line of my question. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( 
 from item in items
 select (from fieldName in fieldsNames
         select item.FieldValues[fieldName]).ToList()
).ToList();
```